# Can't connect to mysql. And mysql fails to restart

Tags: mysql

I have my websites on a VPS - CentOS. Suddenly all of them stopped working and are showing database connection error.
I have tried restarting mysql with the following command in SSH `/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld restart` but when it tries to stop it it says "Failed".
Any idea on what could I do?

Comment: Look in your log files ! Not sure in your case, but try `/var/log/mysqld.log`. Also, try to remember if you have changed anything in your `my.cnf` and tell us about it. And see if you are out of disk space / quota.

Comment: it looks like my /var/log/mysqld.log is 2.837MiB, is that normal? Can I remove it? I have also forgot to mention that I use CentOS, and my host said that the command line I used is not right, but he didn't told me the right one. I haven't edit my.cnf or anything else lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check you mysql log file (/var/log/mysqld.log).

Comment: I have wrote above, in a comment, that mysqld.log is 2.837MiB, it will take few hours to download it, and I don\t even think it is possible to open a file that large on my computer. What do you think?

Comment: I've managed to read it, and it looked like the mysqld.log was taking the entire space on server and the mysql server couldn't start. So, I have removed mysqld.log file and the server created a new blank one, and now it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: First; clear the log file (delete) after that try restart again, and look you log file again